# Potential problem of rxgraph under Ubuntu 12.04 fuerte?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

recently i noticed that rxgraph has some problems and produces the following error message:

```
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rxgraph/impl.py", line 125, in run
    info_text = get_info_text(self.selection_url)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rxgraph/impl.py", line 59, in get_info_text
    return rosnode.get_node_info_description(node_name) + rosnode.get_node_connection_info_description(node_api)
TypeError: get_node_connection_info_description() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This Error is new to me and appeared first time after a ROS updated (ca. 10'th of July). After this error rxgraph is not updatimng any longer the screen, i.e. you can still see the old graph displayed but now response at all to updates on the ROS-Network-Graph.

Here my question: Does any one else have this issue and if yes which OS and ROS version are involved?

As written in the title for me this is Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38919/potential-problem-of-rxgraph-under-ubuntu-12.04-fuerte?/) by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 663 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be a good item for a ticket.

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket

The breakage was caused by this change to ros_comm:

```
r16826 | dthomas | 2012-07-05 22:29:31 +0200 (Thu, 05 Jul 2012) | 1 line

improved output of rosnode info (#3995)
```

It seems rxgraph in the rx package is already fixed, but was not released, so the next release should fix it anyway.

In the meantime, you can also have a look at rosgui / rqt_gui, which has a replacement for rxgraph.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2012-07-16**:
The rx package has been fixed about five days ago.  It will be available as ros-fuerte-rx-1.8.9 as soon as the next sync to the public package repository is performed (likely within the next days).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2012-07-16**:
The corresponding bug report can be found at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4008 and the change log for rx (http://ros.org/wiki/rx/ChangeList/1.8) lists the changes of the upcoming version.